# vector of template struct

Tags: c++, templates, vector

```
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T>
struct ValNode {
    string id;
    T value;
};

class ValTable {
public:
    ValTable();
    template <class T>
    void add(string,T);
    const bool find(string);
    void remove(string);
private:
    template<class T>
    std::vector<ValNode<T>*> vals;
};
```

complier error:`error: data member 'vals' cannot be a member template`

i did try to use T* value in the struct, but i didnt work out.
I didnt use any of the functions in codes yet. was just trying to compling it into *.o file (with .cpp file also).

Comment: You can't do it that way. `ValTable` will have to be a template or you will have to add another template class which holds the vector.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to figure out what `T` is supposed to be on the declaration of  `vals`? Make the whole class template. Bear in mind template classes can't be defined on a .cpp file in general, they must be defined inline on the header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, variables (including data members) can't be templates; only classes and functions can be.

It looks like you want the table to be able to hold values of various different types, specified at run-time according to which types are passed to `add()`. For that, you need *dynamic types*, which aren't directly supported in C++. You might consider libraries like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) for that.

On the other hand, maybe you just want to store a single type in each table, and different types in different tables. In that case, the class itself will need to be a template:

```
template <typename T>
class ValTable {
public:
    ValTable();
    void add(string,T);
    const bool find(string);
    void remove(string);
private:
    std::vector<ValNode<T>*> vals;
};
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. yeah dynamic types was the keyword i was looking for. i think i have to try something else out. thanks for help

Comment: btw, how should I implement a symbol table for various data types all-in-one?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can have template methods in a class, but not template data members.
For example:

```
template<typename T, int n>
struct FixedVector {
    T x[n];
    FixedVector() {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) x[i] = 0;
    }

    template<typename C>
    void copy(const C& container) {
        if (container.size() != n) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong size");
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (typename C::const_iterator i=container.begin(),
                                        e=container.end();
             i!=e;
             ++i)
        {
            x[j++] = *i;
        }
    }
};
```

With the above class you can declare `FixedVector<int, 5> f` and call `f.copy(v)` where `v` can be for example a vector or a list or anything that has `size` `begin` and `end`.
So `FixedVector::copy` is a template **method** and this means that the compiler will generate a different version of it for each different type you will pass to the function.

```
std::vector<double> y;
y.push_back(3.4); y.push_back(5.6); y.push_back(7.8);

std::list<unsigned char> z;
z.push_back('a'); z.push_back('b'); z.push_back('c');

FixedVector<int, 3> v;
v.copy(y);  // This is ok
v.copy(z);  // This is ok too
```

C++ doesn't allow template **data members** because this would imply a different class size depending on how many types you are using in a specific compilation unit and this doesn't go with the C++ compilation model of one-unit-at-a-time.

Adding methods is instead fine because it doesn't affect class size, and everything can be fixed at link time by avoiding pulling multiple copies of the same method from different compilation units.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare `ValTable` as template

```
template <class T>
class ValTable{
public:
    ValTable();
    //template <class T>
    void add(string,T);
    const bool find(string);
    void remove(string);
private:
    //template<class T>
    std::vector<ValNode<T>*> vals;
};
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid this kind of situation. i am trying to make a table that consists different type of data. this wouldn't allow it

Comment: @JoesonHwang I'm sorry but you cannot avoid it.

Comment: @JoesonHwang: That's tricky in a statically-typed language like C++. My answer suggests some libraries that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that `ValTable` needs to be a template

You can have this :

```
template <class T> //Make the class as template
class ValTable {
public:
    ValTable();
    template <class X>
    void add(string,X);
    const bool find(string);
    void remove(string);
private:
    //template<class T>
    std::vector<ValNode<T>*> vals;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have template member values: each translation unit could access different instantiations resulting in different ibject layouts. You'd need to factor out the type in some way.

The standard library does something along the lines of what you want for `std::locale`: each `std::locale` stores a collection of differently typed objects. It is soecial purpose and can't be used for your purpose directly.

The basic idea is to automatically map each type used to an `int` which is then used to map the type to an instance. The `vals` member would then be a function template looking up the correct instance. A rough outline could look like this:

```
int type_index_alloc() { 
    static std::atomic<int> current(0);
    return ++current;
}
template <typename T>
int type_map() {
    static int rc = type_index_alloc();
}
class container {
    struct base { virtual ~base() {} };
    template <typename T>
    struct value: base { T v; };
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<base>> vals_;
public:
    T& vals()  {
        std::shared_ptr<base>& rc(vals_[type_map<T>()]);
        if (!rc) {
            rc = std::make_shared<value<T>>()); }
        return static_cast<value<T>&>(*rc).v;
    }
};
```

This a just trying to show how things are being set up: I currently don't have access to a compiler. Also, the code example just provides access to an object of type `T` but it could easily be changed to use a `std::vector<T>` instead.